# How do I interpret GRAD-CAM's feature attribution to time series zero-padding in a CNN classifier?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, convolutional-neural-network, explainable-ai

#### Problem setting: MTS Classification with CNN architecture

I have a multivariate time series (MTS) dataset that contains 30 features. The goal is to solve a classification problem on this MTS dataset. It is important that I have as much explainability as possible, hence extracting features from the dataset and classifying on them is undesired.

Every MTS in the dataset has a different length. I zero-padded the MTS in the dataset to make them equal length (to length 131).

I use the CNN architecture that is described in the paper [XCM: An Explainable Convolutional Neural Network for Multivariate Time Series Classification](https://inria.hal.science/hal-03469487/document). I used the Python implementation in the [tsai](https://github.com/timeseriesAI/tsai/blob/main/tsai/models/XCM.py) package. I used per-channel standardization on my data.

[image: Image: CNN architecture described in the XCM paper]

#### Problem: GRAD-CAM gives feature attribution to padding

Since this is a CNN architecture, I can use GRAD-CAM on the first Conv 1D layer after the input, indicated in red in the figure above. Visualising the result for a time series of length 27 (+ padding to 131) from the test set, I get the following result, where the y-axis has no meaning, of course, and the x-axis is the time:

[image: Image: GRAD-CAM 1D result on a time series of length 27]

The zero-padding receives a remarkable attribution from GRAD-CAM. I tried this for different test set instances, and the results are equal or sometimes even worse.

My question: **How do I interpret this result? Does the classifier undesirably use the padding for its classification? Can I ignore the feature attribution to the padding and just focus on time stamps 0 to 27? How can I avoid this result?**

---

#### What I already considered

- During my search on the Internet, I found no way of making a CNN ignore padding during training or inference. [Only RNNs seem to have this ability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612736/in-tensorflow-do-i-have-to-set-something-special-to-ignore-zero-padding-value-w), but [they suffer from poor explainability](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.12370.pdf).
- The paper [Effects of padding on LSTMs and CNNs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07288.pdf) only examines the effect on classification accuracy.
- The paper [Time series classification for varying length series](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.04341.pdf) suggest uniform scaling as a pre-processing alternative. However, due to the nature of my time series and the goal of the explainability, this is not a solution for me. Other propositions of the paper are only applicable to univariate time series.
- The most related information I found is a question on this website ([here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/39602/lime-visualization-outputs-padded-regions-as-important-mel-spectrogram-audio)) that encounters the same problem for images. There is no satisfactory answer.
- Applying GRAD-CAM on the 2d convolutional block suffers from the same problem.
- Applying GRAD-CAM on another convolutional MTSC algorithm, such as InceptionTime, suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

GradCAM provides very unintuitive explanations. I've been working on this for the past year and half and I'm still not sure. Maybe you'll find some answers in this paper, under "Local explanations"

https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apenergy.2023.122079